# Java Error handling - is it better to throw Exceptions to centralized error handlers?

Tags: java, error-handling

I've got a decently complex little game going on in Java (solitaire, essentially like the Windows version), but I have yet to do very much error handling.

Almost all of the methods across my classes will end up either getting called by an initial constructor (eventually main()), a paintComponent() method, or a mouse event. So, my question is, is it bad practice to just use "throws Exception" on all of my lower-level methods, and only do a try/catch at my top-level methods to catch ALL the errors at once? (e.g. 3 try/catches - one for the painting, one for mouse events, one for the main method).

I realize this prevents me from easily dealing with errors on-the-spot, but I don't really plan on doing that anyways. My error handling is going to consist of writing to a log, telling the user, and killing the program. Keeping this in mind, is there anything bad with doing my error handling this way?

Comment: No. That seems like an okay way to handle errors.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284699/why-is-it-best-to-not-catch-exceptions-in-general-purpose-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to approach the situation.
If you just want to catch any possible exception and you don't mind about the handler code, you could simply use "throws exception", and there's nothing BAD with it either. It's like a try-catch block that covers all the function.
If you want to write specific code for specific exceptions, you should use try-catch blocks to write appropriate code for each handler.
Based on what you're saying, any caught exception would just notify the user and exit the application. Well, in this case you could just use the first approach. It's not necessarily the BEST approach, and neither is killing the application, however, if that's your strategy you could just use "throws" for each function.
Hope that helps!

Comment: I like the emphasis on choosing between "good enough for now" vs "the right way" in this answer. Nice job, @V0R73X

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you wan't to do in a case of an error, then it makes perfect sense to do it that way. This eliminates code duplication and scattering of related code. However, if you're thinking of changing how things work in the future (if there's a possibility of this happening), I would suggest to try and push the catch down as far as possible (maybe even eliminating the need for exceptions at all and just logging and exiting right away).

If you use the exception's inner fields (specifically `message`, which you can set in construction time), you can even eliminate the need for 3 different catch blocks and just use one (depending on your actual actions in case of an error, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't - the big reason being that it breaks encapsulation. The reason *why* this is important in this case is that your error handling code has one of two futures:

1. Becoming enormous to handle in an informative way every error the program can throw.
2. Be tiny but not helpful at all: "Some error occurred somewhere".

To my mind, the best structure is to catch the error, log it, alert the user, and exit *as far down as possible*. There's nothing that says your mouse handling code can't exit, right?

In fact, I would create an error handler class that you can call from just about anywhere, and it handles the notification and logging. Then your exception handlers can just populate it with the message to display/log, and all other code is shared. It will cost you *less* typing to delegate to this class than adding `throws Exception` at the end of every function everywhere.

If you must have a top level handler, it should just catch any unexpected runtime errors, so that you can log it and show the user that the program is really quitting for an error, and not just dump to the desktop. All other errors - even if you just want to bail out - should be caught as close to "where the exception has meaning" as possible.

Comment: As far as I know, with Java, the error information doesn't get lost when it gets thrown up a level. If I throw an exception in a low-level object, I can still access all the nitty-gritty error info in the higher-level object that catches the error. so it's not going to be "some error occured somewhere" - it will be able to tell me specifically what happened and where

Comment: Well, that's a good point, and true. It depends on how granular your exception handling gets. According to the dependency inversion principle, all you can do in your generic handler is to call methods defined on the generic [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) class - e.g. `getMessage`. If that's good enough, then good enough. If, however, you ever want to handle, to use a stupid example, a MouseException, telling the user "Plug in your mouse, fool", the generic handling can never cleanly tell that you have anything other than a generic Exception.

Comment: Based on your current design, this would seem to be fine - but I personally know my exception handling methods start to smell almost immediately, because exceptions are, by definition, "something's out of kilter somewhere". While I love YAGNI, I tend to over-engineer exceptions right from the beginning, so that I don't create a big ball of mud I can never escape - refactoring exception handling code is a real PITA.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing as you are describing most of the time. What you're basically doing is working around the stupid checked exceptions that Java has. It shouldn't even be necessary to add 'throws Exception' everywhere.

If I'm working on an API that other users will use I may create specific exceptions to show what is going on in case they want to handle different exceptions in different ways.

Comment: I don't know - I think the `throws Exception` being painful was intentional - to tell you to catch the exception as low down as you can and handle it there, even if the handling is to call a `barf` function.

Comment: What I often see is that exceptions end up getting muted and the code keeps executing and then throws a NPE or another exception later in a different place. When this happens we're doing C error handling again: you write one line of code and 4 lines of error handling for everything you do. Exceptions was supposed to fix this so you that don't have error handling code littered all over your application and only in places where you actually want to do something with it such as log the exception - you only need this at the point where the code starts executing.

Comment: I see this a lot too, but this is an "Exception vs. RuntimeException" anti-pattern. Java makes a strict distinction between `Exception`, which is "fixable" and _should_ be handled (e.g. FileNotFoundException: re-ask the user for the path again) and `RuntimeException`s, which are really *errors* (e.g. NullPointerException). RuntimeExceptions don't require a 'throws' declaration. If I want to ignore an Exception, I re-throw it as the cause of a RuntimeException, which is clearer (with valid stack trace), more future-proof (I can fix one at a time), and doesn't bastardize the function interface.

Answer (score 0):

If an error is severe enough to always exit the program, you may be better of throwing a RuntimeException instead. They are used to indicate unrecoverable errors and will avoid problems with putting "throws Exception" everywhere. You should have a handler for RuntimeExceptions anyway to provide a user-friendly error report in case they happen.

If you throw checked exceptions, they should be as specific as possible. Throwing and catching Exception can hide other exceptions that are thrown (including RuntimeExceptions) that you didn't intend and could have been handled differently. If you want to throw a general exception, you can always create your own exception class and throw that instead.

The exception handling can depend on the context so there's not one way to handle everything. If the user clicks a button to open a file and there's an error reading it, then it would be ok to throw an IOException up to the UI layer and display an error message there. On the other hand, an IOException while creating a temporary file could be handled lower down by retrying in another directory.